# Is there an analogue of the fundamental theorem of calculus for probability distributions without a density?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and that we have the values of the integral $$A(s) = \int_0^s x \,d\mu(x) + \int_s^\infty d\mu(x).$$ If $\mu(x) = f(x) \, dx$, we can retrieve $f$, and hence $\mu$ by taking the derivative

$$A'(x) = xf(x) - f(x).$$

If $f$ is differentiable, the second derivative gives $A''(x) = f(x)$ and we now have $\mu$.

What if we don't know that it has a density function, is their any means of effectively retrieving the probability measure?

Comment: There's some ambiguity in writing $\int_0^s x\; d\mu(x)$ and $\int_s^\infty d\mu(x)$ when $\mu$ is a measure, because if $\mu\{s\} > 0$ the results will be different depending on whether or not the endpoint $s$ is to be included in the interval you're integrating over.  Which is it?

Comment: Good point! Let's say the measure is non atomic.

Comment: I don't see why $A''(x) = f(x).$ Differentiating $A'(x) = x f(x) - f(x)$ gives $A''(x) = f(x) + xf'(x) - f'(x).$

Comment: If $A$ is defined as in your post then indeed $A'(x) = xf(x) - f(x)$ but $A''(x)$ is not what you say. Instead what you have in mind might be the function $$A(s) = \int_0^s x \,d\mu(x) + s\int_s^\infty d\mu(x)$$ Then indeed, when $\mu$ has a differentiable density $f$, $$A''=-f$$ To express $A$ directly in terms of $\mu$ in the general case, note that, for every measure $\mu$, with atoms or not, $$A(s) = \int_0^\infty \min(x,s) \,d\mu(x)= \int_0^\infty \int_0^s\mathbf 1_{t<x}\,dt \,d\mu(x)=  \int_0^s\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{t<x} \,d\mu(x)\,dt$$

Comment: ... by (Fubini-)Tonelli, that is, $$A(s) = \int_0^s\int_t^\infty d\mu(x)\,dt=\int_0^s \mu([t,\infty)) \,dt$$

Answer (score -1):

(Assuming the measure is non-atomic) for $h > 0$ we have
$$ (s-1) \mu([s,s+h)) \le A(s+h) - A(s) = \int_s^{s+h} (x-1)\; d\mu(x) \le (s+h-1) \mu([s,s+h))$$

and thus if $s > 1$,
$$  \frac{A(s+h)-A(s)}{s+h-1} \le  \mu([s,s+h)) \le \frac{A(s+h)-A(s)}{s-1}$$
If $s+h < 1$, the inequalities are reversed.
By taking sufficiently fine partitions, we can obtain arbitrarily precise bounds on the measure of an interval.

Comment: But precise bounds on the measures of small intervals will yield not so small errors on the measures on any fixed interval.